# Cypress save cookie value

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I want to save a cookie value using Cypress, but unfortunately I always get undefined in the log console using this code

```
let cookieValue;
cy.getCookie('SOME_COOKIE')
    .should('have.property', 'value')
    .then((cookie) => {
        cookieValue = cookie.value;
    })
cy.log(cookieValue);
```

When I try this

```
let cookieValue;
cy.getCookie('SOME_COOKIE')
    .should('have.property', 'value', 'Dummy value')
    .then((cookie) => {
        cookieValue = cookie.value;
    })
cy.log(cookieValue);
```

I can see the actual value I want in the error message.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer, it could be really helpful for other users landing here with the same issue 

Comment: Sure! thx again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cypress work asynchronously and you can't consume the cookie value as you did.

From [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Using-To-Act-On-A-Subject)

> Want to jump into the command flow and get your hands on the subject directly? No problem, simply add a .then() to your command chain. When the previous command resolves, it will call your callback function with the yielded subject as the first argument.

You should go ahead with your test code inside the `then` callback and not relying on the external `let cookieValue` assignment.

Try this

```
cy.getCookie('SOME_COOKIE')
    .should('have.property', 'value')
    .then((cookie) => {
        cookieValue = cookie.value;
        // YOU SHOULD CONSUME `cookieValue` here
        // .. go ahead inside this `then` callback
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Async and await instead of adding code inside then()

```
const getmyCookie = async (cookiename) => {
    return cy.getCookie(cookiename)
        .should('exist')
        .then(async (c) => {
            cy.log(c.value)
            return c.value
        })
}
```

Use it in your test and ensure your it block is async

```
it('Sample Test', async function () {
   ... some code

   const cookie = await getmyCookie('cookiename')
   cy.log(cookie)

   ... some code
})
```